# Global variable in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-variables

I'm wanting to declare a variable as below for use in several pages on my site.  I assume rather than declaring it once per page I can do it globally?  I've tried it in a class (app_code folder) and in the global.asax page but my code can't seem to find it.  I may be going abo9ut it all wrong though?  Code as below...

```
Dim myUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
```

So basically as it stands my pages can't find the 'myUser' variable.  Any help much appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class/struct and add a static

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Variables
    {
        public static User MembershipUser
        {
            get { return Membership.GetUser(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the value/property using:

MyApp.Variables.MembershipUser

If this GetUser() returns a user object with a property "Username" you can:

```
Hello <%=MyApp.Variables.MembershipUser.Username%>
```

Here's a VB.NET version:

```
 Namespace MyApp
    Public Class Variables
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property MembershipUser() As User
            Get
                Return Membership.GetUser()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Ok I've put the following in a class file:

Public Class Variables
Public Shared myuser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
End Class

and called it using Variables.myUser

Comment: You do not want static (shared) user-specific variables! A static variable has the same value for *all* website users! A static property returning a user-specific value is fine.

Comment: Sorry I think I'm misunderstanding your comment.  You've said that I do not want static user-specific variables, but I do want static user-specific values?

Comment: variables and properties are not the same. You should use a static Property as my example

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) or [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) objects, if you need such a "global".

Use `Session` if needed per user, `Application` if for the whole application.

Comment: If it's the current user I guess it's a Session variable then.  If I put that line in my global.asax file it doesn't work however.  Where should I be putting it?

Comment: @adrian g - What line? Have you changed it to use sessions? I suggest you read the linked document to see how `Session` and `Application` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

This could go in a page base class or in an extension method to `System.Web.UI.Page`

```
public  static MembershipUser GetMembershipUser(this System.Web.UI.Page page)
{
    return Membership.GetUser();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@stian.net I have the following - works exactly as I want it to.  Would you say this was the correct way to do it?

```
Public Class Variables
Public Shared ReadOnly Property myUser As MembershipUser
    Get
        Return Membership.GetUser()
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application("MembershipUser") = "J. Doe"
```

Retrieve it with:

```
MyUser$ = Application("MembershipUser")
```

Note: Global application variables are stored as strings, so if you'd need to store objects, you'll have to serialize them into strings.